# Yammer API to get ONLY MY messages based on Group ID #yammer

Tags: yammer

My requirement is to list all messages sent by a user to a specific Yammer group.

I have used `/api/v1/messages/in_group/` and this returns all recent messages without any option to filter by user.

Is there any API to list messages only from a specific user? Also, how can we increase the number of messages returned by any of the API? The **limit** query parameter works only if the number is below 20

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to filter group messages by user, nor is there a way to avoid having to paginate after each 20 messages. You'll have to paginate back as far as you want and then write a script to extract messages posted by a specified user.